# Pass arguments in forEach -> eventlistener function

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, addeventlistener

How can I solve this?

The code:

```
answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      checkAnswer(div, index);
    });
  });
```

This works, but my function runs four times. (because I have four divs - in my array, in DOM)

How can I achieve this result: (run function only one but still have EventListener for each div)

```
answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer(div, index));
  });
```

I know I can't pass arguments to EventListener.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to ensure that the function is called with the arguments specified.

For example:

```
answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer.bind(null, div, index));
});
```

The first argument to `bind()`, `null` in this case, is what you're binding the `this` value of the function to. So if you reference `this` from inside `checkAnswer`, it'd refer to that first argument.

This example is assuming that you have 4 different divs that each need an event listener. If you just have one div, you could potentially just reverse the structure:

```
div.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // here you can use the "event" arg to get info about what was clicked
    checkAnswer();
});
```

Comment: What does `null` stands for, is the event passed as well?

Comment: Function still runs for times.